# Performing operations on chunks of rows in SQL Server where the identifying column is of type nvarchar

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I'm looking to perform some operations on potentially large data sets in SQL Server 2014. I'd like to do it in chunks (say, ~1000 rows at a time) but the hitch here is that the identity column of the table is an nvarchar type (storing a UUID).

Breaking data into chunks where the IDs are ints is pretty trivial, but I'm left scratching my head on this one. Is there a clean way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an `INT` column to your `SELECT` like this:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT
        (your-usual-list-of-columns),
        RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY -some-column-here-)
    FROM 
        dbo.YourTable
)
SELECT 
    (your-usual-list-of-columns)
FROM 
    CTE
WHERE
    RowNum BETWEEN 1001 AND 1999    --- or whatever batch you want to process
```